# Starting the gotour

Tags: go

I've installed go (and [tested it](http://golang.org/doc/install#testing)). When I run `go env` I see this:

```
$ go env
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go"
GOBIN=""
GOARCH="386"
GOCHAR="8"
GOOS="linux"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="386"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_386"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m32 -pthread"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

However, when I run `go get code.google.com/p/go-tour/gotour` to get started with the tour locally (per [the instructions](http://tour.golang.org/#2)), nothing seems to happen (I get no output, though it does take a couple of seconds to run, which makes me think *something* must have happened).

The instructions say to run the resultant gotour executable, but I can't find one. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I'm starting to feel like I must be pretty dumb, but I just can't figure out what running `go get` did (did it install anything? did it succeed?).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you looked in `/usr/lib/go/bin`? Or, if you set a gopath `$GOPATH/bin`.

By default, `go get` only prints if there was an error. The resultant executable is placed in the GOBIN, the GOROOT bin, or the GOPATH bin.

Answer (score 1):

The `gotour` executable should already be provided by your go installation.

When you run `gotour` without executing the instructed `go get` prior, it should provide you with an import error.

```
2012/07/28 09:10:18 Couldn't find tour files: import "code.google.com/p/go-tour/": cannot find package
```

Running `go get` will get the source - in this case from `code.google.com/p/go-tour` - and place it into your active go environments source folders, in your case `GOROOT="/usr/lib/go"`(, if no `GOPATH` is set). The source will be placed in the subfolder `src/pkg/code.google.com/p/go-tour`.

With the source checked out, running `gotour` again, it can compile its necessary files and use the static files from that repository to serve you the gotour locally. When running `gotour` it should present you with something like

```
2012/07/28 09:10:00 Serving content from C:\Go\src\pkg\code.google.com\p\go-tour
2012/07/28 09:10:00 Serving at http://127.0.0.1:3999/
```

You can then browse the gotour via the address provided.

As a side-note, as as I understood you, you missed this: You don’t need to run it locally. It is merely the gotour website you are browsing, just instantiated locally, though the repository you got via `go get`.

Answer (score 1):

Typing: $GOPATH/bin/gotour
does exactly what you want.